# How to represent this matlab code in mathematical notation?

Tags: notation, maple, symbolic-computation

I have this code in matlab:

```
z = linspace(d1,d2,n)*W/t;
```

I am wondering how to express this operation in mathematical notation?

I was thinking of something like this

[d1 + (N).*((d2 - d1)/(n-1))]*W/t; Where N = 0,1,2,...(n-1)

But is there a fancier or more correct way or clearer way of writing this?

Comment: I think your notation is as clear as it gets.

Comment: So presumably you can avail yourself to the full panoply of mathematical typesetting? Something like $[d_1 + (N)\frac{d_2 - d_1}{n - 1})]{W \over t}$; Where $N = 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n - 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty much it, except that you have to multiply your vector componentwise with $\frac Wt$, so

> z = linspace(d1,d2,n)*W/t

produces a vector $v$ of dimension $n$
$$
a_k:=\left[d_1+k\left(\frac{d_2-d_1}{n-1}\right)\right]\frac Wt,k=0,\ldots,n-1
$$
in the following way
$$
v\equiv(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})
$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context, but I would write it as,

$$
z = \left\{
\frac{W\cdot d_1}{t}, \frac{W\cdot d_1 + W\cdot(d_2-d_1)/(n-1)}{t}, \cdots, \frac{W\cdot d_2}{t}
\right\}
$$
which is easier to understand than giving an explicit series.